# Error when transport.write() from thread in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to make this simple server script where multiple clients connect to it and are stored in the factory.connected_clients dictionary. I then want to show a menu so the user executing the server can select what client does he want to work with and what commands does he want to send them (like in a reverse shell). Here's the code:

```
class RshServer(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory, addr):
        self.addr = addr
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        address = self.addr.host + ':' + str(self.addr.port)
        self.factory.connected_clients[address] = self
        print '[*] Connection made with ' + address

class RshFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected_clients = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return RshServer(self, addr)

def show_server_menu():
    print '1. Show connected clients'
    print '2. Open client interface'
    msg = raw_input('Select an option: ')
    return msg

def show_client_menu():
    print '1. Show all processes'
    msg = raw_input('Select an option: ')
    return msg

def server_interface():
    while 1:
        msg = show_server_menu()
        command = server_commands.get(msg, None)
        if command: command()

def client_interface():
    protocol_name = raw_input('Enter client address: ')
    protoc = rsh_factory.connected_clients.get(protocol_name, None)
    if protoc: 
        msg = show_client_menu()
        protoc.transport.write(msg) 


rsh_factory = RshFactory()

server_commands = {
    '1' : lambda: sys.stdout.write(str(rsh_factory.connected_clients)+'\n'),
    '2' : client_interface
}

reactor.listenTCP(8000, rsh_factory)
reactor.callInThread(server_interface)
reactor.run()
```

However, when I select a client and execute the client interface function I get this error:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rsh_twisted_serv.py", line 58, in <module>
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1204, in mainLoop
    self.doIteration(t)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 396, in doPoll
    log.callWithLogger(selectable, _drdw, selectable, fd, event)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 88, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 627, in _doReadOrWrite
    self._disconnectSelectable(selectable, why, inRead)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 257, in _disconnectSelectable
    selectable.readConnectionLost(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 279, in readConnectionLost
    self.connectionLost(reason)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 293, in connectionLost
    abstract.FileDescriptor.connectionLost(self, reason)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 207, in connectionLost
    self.stopWriting()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 429, in stopWriting
    self.reactor.removeWriter(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 344, in removeWriter
    EPOLLOUT, EPOLLIN)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 321, in _remove
    self._poller.unregister(fd)
exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I believe this is error is due to the transport.write() being called from a non-reactor thread. Am I right? How should I solve this?

**SOLUTION:** as @Glyph stated, the problem was indeed that I was calling transport.write() from a non-reactor thread (more details in his answer). I used the solution he proposed by changing `protoc.transport.write()` to `reactor.callFromThread(lambda: protoc.transport.write(msg))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "called from a *non*-reactor thread".  No code in Twisted is thread-safe unless explicitly specified.  See the [threading documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.1/core/howto/threading.html#running-code-in-a-thread-safe-manner) for more information.  Use [`reactor.callFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.1/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html#callFromThread) to invoke Twisted methods from your stdio-reading thread, or use [`StandardIO`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.1/api/twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO.html) to tell Twisted to read from standard input instead.

Comment: I meant non-reactor thread, yes. I mixed my words.

Your answer was exactly what I needed. Many thanks!